# how to turn my laptop into a speaker?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio

i want every sound (not only music) of my phone to play in my laptop. For example:
I am playing a game on my phone but the sound should come from my laptop.

I even bought a 3.5mm male to male audio jack but still it is not working.

[image]

I use a windows 10 DELL laptop, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you hope to gain? Even if you manage it [which depends on your phone as much as your laptop] the sound will be delayed, by as much as half a second.

Comment: Without more detail such as make and model, this question is too broad—maybe even if not. Start by ensuring the latest device drivers for the audio are installed onto the OS. Give detail about your configuration too such as this goes to a . . .

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're likely connecting your phone as a microphone to your computer. You will need to have some form of output setup in order to listen to your recording.

Right click on the speaker icon on the lower right corner of your screen and select "Recording devices". Find your plugged in recording devices and open its properties. Check the "Listen" tab and select "Listen to this device". That way whatever is being recorded should be played back right away.